# how can i generate a number of round in random number gucessing game, how can i improve my code

Tags: java

```
int number_of_rounds = (int)(Math.abs(Math.log10(ma-mi+1)/Math.log10(2)));
```

how can i generate positive integer value, I am new here so if i do any mistake please guide me

Comment: In which way does the code you show not work? Pleas provide a [mre] which demonstrates that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-do-i-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

To generate positive integer numbers you simply need the Random class and invoke the nextInt(int bound) method. This method will return an integer value between 0 and bound-1. If you need a value between a and b, then you can simply add *a* as an offset of the nextInt result and use *(b - a)* as the upper bound.

For example:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int x = rand.nextInt(10);       //returns an integer between 0 and 9
int y = rand.nextInt(10) + 10;  //returns an integer between 10 and 19
```